# Getting a Column's Max Value

Tags: mysql, database

Is there any tangible difference (speed/efficiency) between these statements? Assume the column is indexed.

```
SELECT MAX(someIntColumn) AS someIntColumn
```

or

```
SELECT someIntColumn ORDER BY someIntColumn DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This depends largely on the query optimizer in your SQL implementation. At best, they will have the same performance. Typically, however, the first query is potentially much faster.

The first query essentially asks for the DBMS to inspect every value in `someIntColumn` and pick the largest one.

The second query asks the DBMS to sort all the values in `someIntColumn` from largest to smallest and pick the first one. Depending on the number of rows in the table and the existence (or lack thereof) of an index on the column, this could be significantly slower.

If the query optimizer is sophisticated enough to realize that the second query is equivalent to the first one, you are in luck. But if you retarget your app to another DBMS, you might get unexpectedly poor performance.

Comment: I agree with this. MAX() gives the DBMS a clear goal and the opportunity to use whatever optimization it has in place for that case (say, a super-fast "max" lookup that gets updated only if a column gets inserted that is higher). The second command is harder for the system to understand in its intent, and possibly more difficult to optimize.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT based on explain plan:

Explain plan shows that `max(column)` is more efficient. The explain plan say, `“Select tables optimized away”`.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT version from schema_migrations order by version desc limit 1;
+----+-------------+-------------------+-------+---------------+--------------------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table             | type  | possible_keys | key                      | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------------+-------+---------------+--------------------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | schema_migrations | index | NULL          | unique_schema_migrations | 767     | NULL |    1 | Using index | 
+----+-------------+-------------------+-------+---------------+--------------------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

EXPLAIN SELECT max(version) FROM schema_migrations ;
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                        |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | NULL  | NULL | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | NULL | Select tables optimized away | 
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Right, suppose I should clarify, that this is just to retrieve that single column value.

Comment: Yes indeed. myISAM is real fast at returning summary results from indexed columns; it maintains the summary data in a usable fashion.